# Is there a single word that means "non-recursive datatype with two constructors"?

Tags: haskell, naming, nomenclature, algebraic-data-types

Is there a word that describes data types that

1. have exactly two constructors; and
2. are not recursive?

i.e. describes these types

```
data Bool = False | True
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
data Either l r = Left l | Right r
```

but excludes these types

```
data Ordering = LT | EQ | GT  -- too many constructors
data () = ()                  -- too few constructors
data [a] = a | a : [a]        -- recursive definition
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such word. Perhaps this is for a reason.

Comment: I was thinking about this these days, and I thought about "binary" or "dual" (this one may not be always applicable).

Comment: Would you call "data Foo a = One a | Many [a]" be a recursive type according to your standard?

Comment: @Chris No, because Foo does not appear in its definition.

Answer (score 3):

I think the trait of having exactly two constructors is quite meaningless. Imagine the types:

```
data StrictOrdering = LT | GT
data Ordering' = EQ | NEQ !StrictOrdering
```

The type `Ordering'` is equivalent to the `Ordering` you mentioned, differing only in '2-constructorness'.

On the other hand, `Maybe Bool`, `Either Bool Bool` and `Bool` are very different and don't seem to deserve the same name except for being called 'sum types'.

Now, one may find some similarities between `exists a. Maybe a` and `Bool`, but to point them out one needs more constraints than just '2-constructorness'.

Answer (score 2):

"Having two constructors" is a property that carries little information about what can be represented by such a type.  It means forcing to weak-head-normal-form (WHNF) allows a binary choice in a case statement.  Perhaps you could call it a ***"Two Headed Type"*** to coin a phrase.

It is more useful to GHC as a way to create an optimized representation in RAM for the data, since [GHC uses pointer tagging](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/HaskellExecution/PointerTagging) which helps for types up to 4 constructors (or 8 on 64-bit machines).

Answer (score 1):

How about *nonrecursive two-constructor sum-type*?

Comment: It's a bit long. Why "product"?

Answer (score 0):

What about a binary sum/coproduct type (of two types)?